# Why does GWT generate permutations having the same strong name?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, localization

I am trying to debug an issue in my GWT application that cache.html files are not downloaded to the browser for certain languages.I compiled the code with the DEBUG flag on, and saw that for that particular module, successive permutations have the same names. Eg.

```
[INFO]    Permutation 0 (strong name 69FCD2BE193AD6EDC4FD6FDEF49874E4) has an initial download size of 98999 and total script size of 98999
[INFO]    Permutation 1 (strong name 69FCD2BE193AD6EDC4FD6FDEF49874E4) has an initial download size of 98999 and total script size of 98999
[INFO]    Permutation 2 (strong name 69FCD2BE193AD6EDC4FD6FDEF49874E4) has an initial download size of 98999 and total script size of 98999
[INFO]    Permutation 3 (strong name 658D84625663D1AD2C6C092B59783BA2) has an initial download size of 99004 and total script size of 99004
[INFO]    Permutation 4 (strong name 69FCD2BE193AD6EDC4FD6FDEF49874E4) has an initial download size of 98999 and total script size of 98999
[INFO]    Permutation 5 (strong name 69FCD2BE193AD6EDC4FD6FDEF49874E4) has an initial download size of 98999 and total script size of 98999
[INFO]    Permutation 6 (strong name 979A66F54677F53C0E4A1E29A2C00FE5) has an initial download size of 94649 and total script size of 94649
[INFO]    Permutation 7 (strong name 979A66F54677F53C0E4A1E29A2C00FE5) has an initial download size of 94649 and total script size of 94649
[INFO]    Permutation 8 (strong name 979A66F54677F53C0E4A1E29A2C00FE5) has an initial download size of 94649 and total script size of 94649
```

I have verified that the particular module has all the entries related to the languages in its gwt.xml file. Eg.

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en_US" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="nl" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="da" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="de" />
```

What could be a possible reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The 'strong' part of the strong name means that the name is linked to the contents, so if the contents are the same, then the name is the same. The letters and numbers come from a hash of the files own contents - if permutation 0 and 1 have the same name, that means they also have the same contents. Since they have the same contents, you only need to have one copy of the file.

Do your various locales have different sets of strings, or are some of them just copies of others (or empty)? Do you have other property configurations besides locale, and what do they do? The answers to these questions will help to explain why you have so many permutations and which ones don't make sense and can be removed.